# Access Runtime Docker ENV variables in Webpack React Project

Tags: reactjs, docker, webpack

I am working on a Dockerized webpack react frontend app. I need the ability to access the runtime variable passed in docker CONTAINER run command with -e flag for my api url. I have defined my env variable in Dockerfile. However, I am not able to access it using process.env.REACT_APP_NAME. I tried same method with a basic CRA app and it worked there. Is this issue related to webpack? I know webpack set env variables at build time but that's not what I want as it will expose critical information in my frontend code.

```
docker run -e REACT_APP_NAME=XYZ -p 3000:3000 -d dockerized-react
```

Above is my command and I am not able to access in webpack based project using process.env but same works flawlessly in CRA app

Webpack file:

```
const MiniCSSExtractCss = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const HTMLWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");

let mode = "development";

if (process.env.NODE_ENV) {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV.trim() === "production") {
    mode = "production";
  }
}

module.exports = {
  mode: mode,
  cache: {
    type: "filesystem",
  },

  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    assetModuleFilename: "assets/[hash][ext][query]",
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(jsx?|ts)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
        },
      },

      {
        test: /\.s?css$/,
        use: [
          MiniCSSExtractCss.loader,
          "css-loader",
          "resolve-url-loader",
          "postcss-loader",
          "sass-loader",
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.woff2(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
        loader: "file-loader",
      },
      {
        test: /\.woff(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
        loader: "file-loader",
      },
      // {
      //   test: /\.ttf(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
      //   loader: "file-loader",
      // },
      {
        test: /\.(eot|otf)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
        loader: "file-loader",
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|svg|gif|eot)$/i,
        type: "asset",
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/i,
        type: "asset",
      },
    ],
  },

  optimization: {
    // minimize: true,
  },

  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),

    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      process: "process/browser",
    }),
    new MiniCSSExtractCss(),
    new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./src/index.html",
      favicon: "./src/assets/favicon.png",
    }),
  ],

  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".ts"],
  },
  devtool: "eval-cheap-module-source-map",
  devServer: {
    //contentBase: "./dist",
    historyApiFallback: true,
    hot: true,
  },
};
```

Comment: Never store secret information in frontend no matter where they come from. Show your `webpack.config.js` file

Comment: @LinDu - That's the whole point to pass variable with container run command. So, I do not save anything on frontend. I have attached my webpack file. Passing variable is working with CRA but not with my custom webpack based project.

Comment: Can you try add [DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) or [EnvironmentPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/environment-plugin/) for webpack

Comment: @LinDu - That does not work because variables defined using those are defined at build time and cannot be changed later. Already tried that.

Comment: So you want to access the environment variables via `process.env` in frontend at runtime in a real time?

Comment: Yes, tried with CRA and it worked. This command works with CRA and i am able to get apiurl but with webpack it is undefined.

docker run -e MY_VAR=www.api.com -p 3000:3000 -d dockerized-react